# Book Identification: Only Remember Concept of Book Art

Tags: story-identification

There was a book in the main level stacks at a college library when I was a teen, which I believe was part of a series, and may have later been made into a movie.  The general concept of the artwork was such:

There is a woman, in furs, possibly bear skins, who is on the plains.  If memory recalls, she had blonde hair.  From the memory of the book's description, it was a somewhat adventurous tale of the life of the character on the cover, but more so, and about their nomadic lifestyle.

If it helps, it was in the same section as sci fi/fantasy books, including *The Wheel of Time* series, by Robert Jordan (which is the book I chose, rather than this one... and I never got back to it because of *WoT*).  Also, this book was available in the stacks by at least 1995, so I am guessing the book could have been written between the 1980s and early-to-mid '90s.

One final note: I think there was only two or three of these books in the series, but I could be wrong.  They were larger in size (at least 600 pages from the thickness, more likely closer to 8-900).

Comment: Might be the Helliconia series by Brian Aldiss, need to check a few things before making an answer.

Comment: After a bit more checking I don't think it's the Helliconia series after all. Certainly no cover I could find that matches the description.

Comment: Honestly, fantasy art featuring a woman not-too-well-covered in animal skins is so massively common that you're going to have problems narrowing down the book just based on this!

Comment: @Graham If you're talking about my 27-year old memory description, it looks like I will not have any issues, as the answer by Buzz is correct.  :)

https://lawntonbooks.com.au/book/the-clan-of-the-cave-bear/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This sounds like something from the *[Earth's Children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_Children)* series (also known as the *Clan of the Cave Bear* series, after the first—and best remembered—book) by [Jean M. Auel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_M._Auel).  There are six novels in the series, published starting in 1980.  They were all quite thick; the first two were about 500 pages each, and the later ones more like 750.  After the first book was wildly successful, the sequels were all marketed as hardcover bestsellers, like Robert Jordan's *Wheel of Time* books.  The first book was also made into a film starring Daryl Hannah that was released in 1986.

The heroine was the blond-haired *Homo sapiens sapiens* Ayla, who was raised by the eponymous *Homo sapiens neanderthalensis* clan in the first book, then set off on adventures of her own in the later novels.  If the particular novel you are thinking of took place largely in plains terrain, it might have been the second volume, *[The Valley of Horses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Valley_of_Horses)* (1982) or the fourth *[The Plains of Passage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Plains_of_Passage)* (1990).

This might have been the cover you saw, although there are a number of others that it might have been (for either *The Valley or Horses* or for one of the other books).

[image: The Valley of Horses]

Comment: @JW Thanks.  I misremembered and didn't bother to count.

Comment: Ah, right...as soon as I read the beginning of your comment, I asked myself "Why couldn't you remember that?" LOL

Thanks so much...I've never gotten to read or listen to them, but have always meant to.

Comment: This is the cover I remember from Clan of the Cave Bear, which I only passingly described with any amount of accuracy:  https://lawntonbooks.com.au/book/the-clan-of-the-cave-bear/  It looks like, from piddling online for more covers in the series, that I somewhat remembered elements from a few of them as a single piece of art.